# Spring Redis performance

Tags: spring, performance, caching, redis

I'm working on fetching huge amount of data(millions of records) and plan is to keep frequent records in cache and fetch from cache for quick responses. I'm using `NoSQL` database and have around 35k records in the cache. I'm using this piece of code to check if its cached,

```
redistemplate.opsForHash().entries("key").size() == 0,
```

if the condition satifies,

```
redistemplate.opsForHash().put("key", "KeyValue", List);
```

if not,

```
(List) redistemplate.opsForHash().entries("Key").get("KeyValue");
```

But when I'm checking the performance, fetching from DB is faster than fetching from cache. I'm just trying the basic `redis` caching, not sure if it is recommended. Please provide inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with entries.. why !?
You can use template function directly to access keys or values.

To check the condition:

```
redisTemplate.hasKey("key");
```

if doesn't satisfy:

```
redistemplate.opsForHash().put("key", "hashKey", List);
```

else

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("key", "hashKey");
```

I think this will enhance the performance.

on the other hand, try to find where the delay exactly is. ie. which call is causing the delay?

Comment: if you got any documentation on spring redis and redis, please guide me.

Comment: find below links: Redis Hash Performance Case Study (http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value) , Spring Data Official Documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/), and Redis Official Documentation about Memory Performance (http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization)

Comment: if you find last comment of documentation is helpful please vote up!

Comment: I have posted another question, please provide your input. I wanted to know if the cached object can be modified and updated in the cache itself before storing into DB.

Answer (score 1):

I made another way of resolving it, instead of OpsForHash, I tried OpsForList which is much faster.